# How to pass the desired capabilities at the command line level to pybot

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

How can I pass the Desired Capabilities to run my scripts on Desktop and Mobile Browsers, Tablets and Mobile devices on various Operating Systems ?

I would like to use the same as a Shell command in the Jenkins Build step. It should work on both windows or linux servers as Jenkins host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to define the capabilities as a variable that you can use in your test scripts, and put these definitions in an [argument file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#argument-files). By putting them in an argument file you are guaranteed that everyone uses the same capabilities consistently.

For example, create a file named "android.args" and put something like this in it:

```
--variable desired_capabilities:platformName:Android,platformVersion:5.0
--variable remote_url:http://localhost:1234
```

You can create another file named "desktop.ie.args" that might like this:

```
--variable  desired_capabilities:platformName:Windows,platformVersion:10.0
--variable  remote_url:http://localhost:1235
```

... and so on for every configuration. You would then reference these capabilities in your robot tests with `${desired_capabilities}`. For example:

```
[Suite Setup]  open browser  
    ...  http://www.example.com
    ...  remote_url=${remote_url}
    ...  desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}
```

You can then run your tests on different platforms like this:

```
robot -A android.args my_test_suite
robot -A desktop.ie.args my_test_suite
...
```

Even better, you can create your own wrapper around robot so that you can do something even simpler, such as:

```
mybot android my_test_suite
```

where "mybot" takes the first argument, looks for a file with that name and the ".args" suffix in known location, and automatically adds the arguments "-A /path/to/android.args" when running the actual robot command.

Comment: Thank you @Bryan for your valuable advice as always. Very helpful. Sure, I will organize my tests to utilize the argument files as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

```
pybot -v desired_capabilities:"deviceName:Android Emulator,platformName:Android,platformVersion:5.1,deviceOrientation:portrait,browserName:Browser,appiumVersion:1.5.3,deviceType:phone" -i mobile workspace\my_tests
```

Note: you can also parameterize the values with ${BROWSER} and pass the values to it from the script or from a python variable file.